# Getting indexOutOfBOundException 0

Tags: java

Why do I keep getting `indexOutOfBOundException` 0 on the following line?:

```
rotatedShape[r][c] = shape[c][height-1-r];
```

The method `rotateCW()` turns a `char[][]` by 90 degrees clockwise but Im keep getting the error. Could smb please take a look? thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    CreateShape temp = new CreateShape(10,10, 'a', 
        new char[][]{{'x','.','.'}, 
                     {'.','.','x'}, 
                     {'x','.','x'}}, 
        "x . .\n"
        + ". . x\n"
        + "x . x");   
    temp.rotateCW();
    System.out.println(temp);
}

public class CreateShape implements Shape {

    private String tempLayout  = "";
    private String layout;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private char dc;
    private Rotation initialPos;
    private Rotation nextPos;
    private char[][] shape; 
    private char[][] rotatedShape = new char[height][width];// = new char[shape.length][shape[0].length];


    public CreateShape(int height, int width, char dc, char[][] charLayout, String layout)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.dc = dc;
        this.shape = charLayout;
        this.layout = layout;
        initialPos = Rotation.CW0;
    }

    public void rotateCW() 
    {
    //  String tempLayout = "";
        nextPos = initialPos.next();

        /*for(int r = 0; r < height; r++)
            for(int c = 0; c < width; c++)
            {
                rotatedShape[c][height-1-r] = shape[r][c];
                layout += rotatedShape[c][height-1-r];
            }*/
        for(int r = 0; r < height; r++)
            for(int c = 0; c < width; c++)
            {
                rotatedShape[r][c] = shape[c][height-1-r];
                tempLayout += rotatedShape[r][c];

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: please add your stack trace

Comment: Where is `rotatedShape` initialized? The error is telling you that one of your array dimensions is not initialized to a size > 0. Same with `shape`. You need to post more code, we're not getting the whole picture. Also, stack trace please.

Comment: Where is `rotatedShape` declared? Where is `nextPos` declared? Where is `tempLayout` declared?

Comment: where is Rotation ? .... class or enumerate

Comment: My bad, the code is updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CreateShape temp = new CreateShape(10,10, 'a', new char[][]{{'x','.','.'}, 
                                                                  {'.','.','x'}, 
                                                                  {'x','.','x'}}, "x . .\n"
                                                                                + ". . x\n"
                                                                                + "x . x");
```

You are passing in a width and height of 10, but your array is only 3x3.  You then proceed to loop through the 3x3 array (`shape`) based on the width/height of 10.

```
for(int r = 0; r < height; r++)
        for(int c = 0; c < width; c++)
        {
            rotatedShape[r][c] = shape[c][height-1-r];
            tempLayout += rotatedShape[r][c];

        }
}
```

10 is greater than 3.  This will obviously cause an `IndexOutOfBounds` exception.

Comment: I tried everything including changing the dimensions. Doesnt help

Comment: Changing the dimensions to 3x3 may not eliminate all errors, but using the wrong dimensions will certainly add errors.

Comment: This *may* be a legitimate bug in the program, but this is **not** the answer.  There is something else that is *very* wrong with the declaration of the `rotatedShape` array.

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating your array before you know how tall and wide it's going to be.  Specifically, these three declarations are what's breaking you:

```
private int height;
private int width;
private char[][] rotatedShape = new char[height][width];
```

Java has a special rule about unassigned variables at construction time.  If they are not assigned, [they are assigned to an initial value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).  For primitives and `boolean`, it's 0 and `false` respectively; for objects, it's `null`.

What you've done here is effectively create an array of size (0, 0), which is why you're going out of bounds *any time* you index into it.

My gut feeling tells me you don't need the `height` or `width` fields.  What you'd want to do instead is declare `rotatedShape` - just declare it, don't instantiate it.

```
private char[][] rotatedShape;
```

Inside the constructor, when you *know* the height and width, *then* and only then could you properly instantiate the array.

```
public CreateShape(int height, int width, char dc,
                   char[][] charLayout, String layout) {
    this.dc = dc;
    this.shape = charLayout;
    this.layout = layout;
    initialPos = Rotation.CW0;
    rotatedShape = new char[height][width];
}
```