# Array storage interface JAVA Probably easy to solve

Tags: java, arrays, interface

I have an issue. I am designing an interface using java applet and I wanted to make a **sign-up button** which takes the *username, password, gender and age* and stores them in an array; and from the array to a **`.txt`** file. The file will later be used to verify the user when they try to log in using the log-in button.

There seems to be a ***problem at the array*** but I do not know what is wrong. I am also pretty bad at programming, so maybe for others this would seem silly. Unfortunately, my reputation is just 1 so I cannot post a picture of the interface but I assume you can see it with the aid of the code.

My code is too big to be posted here so I will just attach a link to my Netbeans folder:
[CODE zip file](http://www.filedropper.com/gui_1)

```
public class Interface extends javax.swing.JApplet {
private int year=2015;
private int year2=2015;
private int month=1;
private int month2=4;
private int day=1;
private int day2=28;
private int n;
private int age=0;
private String gender= "M";
private String[][] logData = new String[4][n];
private void jSlider1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      

    int v = jSlider1.getValue();
    String vv = Integer.toString(v);
    jTextField2.setText(vv);
}                                     

private void jSlider2StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
    int v1 = jSlider2.getValue();
    String vv1 = Integer.toString(v1);
    jTextField4.setText(vv1);
}                                     

private void jToggleButton2StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                            
    boolean slct = jToggleButton2.isSelected();
    if (!slct)
        jTextField5.setText("ON");
    else
        jTextField5.setText("OFF");
}                                           

private void jSlider3StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
    int v2 = jSlider3.getValue();
    String vv2 = Integer.toString(v2);
    jTextField7.setText(vv2);
}                                     

private void jSlider4StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {                                      
    int v3 = jSlider4.getValue();
    String vv3 = Integer.toString(v3);
    jTextField9.setText(vv3);
}                                     

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The system will shut down");
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The system will restart");
}                                        

private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    int k = jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
    year=2015-k;
    jTextField3.setText(Integer.toString(year));
}                                           

private void jComboBox2ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    int k = jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex();
    month = k+1;
    jTextField8.setText(Integer.toString(month));
}                                           

private void jComboBox3ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    int k = jComboBox3.getSelectedIndex();
    day = k+1;

    switch (month){
        case 2:
            if (year%4==0){
                if (day>29)
                    day=29;
            }
            if (year%4!=0){
                if (day>28)
                    day=28;
            }
        case 4:
            if (day>30)
                day=30;
            break;
        case 6:
            if (day>30)
                day=30;
            break;
        case 9:
            if (day>30)
                day=30;
            break;
        case 11:
            if (day>30)
                day=30;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    jTextField10.setText(Integer.toString(day));


}                                           

private void jTextField3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                           

private void jComboBox5ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    int k = jComboBox5.getSelectedIndex();
    year2=2015-k;
    jTextField11.setText(Integer.toString(year2));
}                                           

private void jComboBox6ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    int k = jComboBox6.getSelectedIndex();
    month2 = k+1;
    jTextField12.setText(Integer.toString(month2));
}                                           

private void jComboBox7ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    int k = jComboBox7.getSelectedIndex();
    day2 = k+1;

    switch (month2){
        case 2:
            if (year2%4==0){
                if (day2>29)
                    day2=29;
            }
            if (year2%4!=0){
                if (day2>28)
                    day2=28;
            }
        case 4:
            if (day2>30)
                day2=30;
            break;
        case 6:
            if (day2>30)
                day2=30;
            break;
        case 9:
            if (day2>30)
                day2=30;
            break;
        case 11:
            if (day2>30)
                day2=30;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    jTextField13.setText(Integer.toString(day2));
}                                           

private void jTextField11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                            

private void jComboBox5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                          

private void jButton4MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       

    n++;
    if(month2<month)
        age=year2-year-1;
    if((month2==month)&&(day2<day))
        age=year2-year-1;
    if ((month2==month)&&(day2>=day))
        age=year2-year;
    if (month2>month)
        age=year2-year;
    String ageStr=Integer.toString(age);
    if(jComboBox4.getSelectedIndex()==1)
        gender="F";
    else
        gender="M";
    if ((jTextField6.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))&&(jPasswordField2.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")))
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            logData[0][i]=jTextField6.getText();
            logData[1][i]=jPasswordField2.getText();
            logData[2][i]=ageStr;
            logData[3][i]=gender;               
        }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registration successful");
    //System.out.println(logData[0][0]);
File log = new File("out.txt");
try{
if(log.exists()==false){
        log.createNewFile();
}
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(log, true));
//out.println(logData[0][0]);
out.close();
}catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("COULD NOT LOG!!");
}
}
```

So every time I try to print the values of the array logData anyhow, I get the following errors:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Interface.jButton4MouseReleased(Interface.java:1002)
    at Interface.access$700(Interface.java:23)
    at Interface$8.mouseReleased(Interface.java:264)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: Instead of posting a picture or a ZIP file, you could copy and paste in the relevant part of the code that's giving you problems.

Comment: Well, since I don't know exactly where the problem comes from, I chose to give you the whole file so you can run it. I am sorry if I chose poorly.

Comment: Think about it critically.  Do you get an error message from the command line?  That's information that'll tell you where it's going wrong.  Do you get no compilation or run time errors, but the output is wrong?  That's important too - we need to know what data you're putting in and what you're getting out and why you think it's incorrect.

Comment: Please isolate the code causing the problem and include in the post.

Comment: ok, I edited my post.. I hope this makes it more clear..

Comment: Ok, I am stupid... I forgot to initialize n

Comment: alright.. i initialized n with 1 but I am still not getting what I need in the arrays. I printed the logData for i=0 and I got "null" for all four cells.            
System.out.println("1. " + logData[0][0]);
System.out.println("2. " + logData[1][0]);
System.out.println("3. " + logData[2][0]);
System.out.println("4. " + logData[3][0]);  

returned

1. null
2. null
3. null
4. null

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What are you asking again?  Your original question looks to be [related to this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29870604/1079354) which is why I circled back on it, but are you asking something different now?

Comment: Nevermind, I debugged it. The problems were: n was not initialized, the if ((jTextField6.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))&&(jPasswordField2.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(""))) statement was wrong.. in worst case scenario it should have had negations for both conditions, and the biggest mistake was that I was assigning values to logData[0][n] instead of logData[0][n-1]. I'm glad I found the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to always be dealing with the same number of items, why don't you use a Map instead of a multi-dimensional string array?

```
Map vehicles = new HashMap();
vehicles.put("BMW", 5);
vehicles.put("Mercedes", 3);
vehicles.put("Audi", 4);
vehicles.put("Ford", 10);
```

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-map-example/

or for you:

```
Map logData = new HashMap();
logData.put("jTextField6", jTextField6.getText());
logData.put("jPasswordField2", jPasswordField2.getText());
logData.put("age", ageStr);
logData.put("gender", gender);
```

Then you can get rid of that awkward for loop in `jButton4MouseReleased`. If you have to keep track of invocations of `jButton4MouseReleased` you can use an array of attempts like this:

```
List attempts = new ArrayList();
Map logData = new HashMap();
logData.put("jTextField6", jTextField6.getText());
logData.put("jPasswordField2", jPasswordField2.getText());
logData.put("age", ageStr);
logData.put("gender", gender);
attempts.add(logData);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so much better!

Comment: Cool, if this answered your question, please check the checkmark by the answer. Good luck!